# is there any way to check who modifies the object in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an Oracle database in which multiple users are connecting to with same user credentials from different machines, is there any way to check who modifies certain database trigger

Answer (score 0):

I believe so, if you (actually, a DBA, and I'm not the one) enable [auditing](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/AUDIT-Traditional-Auditing.html#GUID-ADF45B07-547A-4096-8144-50241FA2D8DD). *Action* you'd audit would be `alter trigger`. Then you'd query [dba_audit_trail](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/refrn/DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL.html#GUID-A9993FAC-12D3-4725-A37D-938CC32D74CC) and see which info has been gathered.

Comment: the changes are already made by one of the user, i just need to check the history... also be informed there is no auditing enabled on this Database

Comment: In that case, I'd say that you're out of luck. Without auditing, the only way to know who modified that trigger is to **ask developers** who have privileges to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You *must* have auditing enabled to capture DDL events, and you *must* prevent users from using a common login, if possible.

Without an audit trail, there is no reviewable history of changes made. This can be just as important in development environments as in production.

With all users sharing one login, it can be difficult to determine who is doing what, even with auditing. One strategy to control use of common accounts is to use proxy user connections, as described here: https://pmdba.wordpress.com/2021/10/15/shared-application-accounts-revisited/. In most cases this introduces enough detail in the audit logs to know who did what.